# Python3 + Threading + Gtk3 + MessageDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, gtk, gtk3

I'm working with threading and Gtk.MessageDialog with this Thread:

```
class DialogueAttente(Thread):
def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.message=Gtk.MessageDialog(None,Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,Gtk.MessageType.INFO,Gtk.ButtonsType.NONE,"Diagnostic en cours")

def run(self):
    self.message.run()

def join(self):
    self.message.destroy()
```

This runs great when I call it, the first time. But when it's called a second time (or third etc ...), the MesageDialog comes up, but the body is transparent, without any message.

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ (like most toolkits) is not thread-safe. You can create threads, but you can only use them to pass data to the main thread used by GTK+.

See https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I did turn to another solution, but I keep the thread alive. Actually my other solution is to build a new Gtk.MessageDialog as a button is clicked, with a set_modal(False) and no run() method, but instead playing with show() and hide().

I still have a problem with this, because MessageDialog appears with the transparent body ...